# Marionette 2.4.4 LayoutView's childEvents not firing?

Tags: javascript, marionette

I have a LayoutView that handles showing it's own children. According to the documentation, I can extend the `childEvents` object to automagically listen for any events triggered on it's child views.

This isn't working for me at all. Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong?

```
Show.QuizLayout = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template:_.template("<h3><%= title %></h3><div id='quiz'></div>"),
    regions: {
        card: "#quiz",
    },
    childEvents: {
        "next:question": "showNextQuestion",
    },
    showNextQuestion:function () {
        //I NEVER GET CALLED!!!
    },
    onShow:function(){
        var v = new Show.QuizCard();
        this.showChildView('card',v)
});

Show.QuizCard = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    className: "quizcard",
    template: _.template("<div class='card' id='next'>Next</div>"),
    events: {
        "click #next":function(e){
            this.trigger("next:question")
       }
    },
});
```

I have gotten around this by setting `v.on("next:question", function(){...})`, but it creates cruft I'd rather not have to deal with, if I could get `childEvents` to work the way they're supposed to.

Comment: I know that they were only added in 2.4.0, and the title was changed to `childViewEvents` in 3.x,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.5/marionette.layoutview.html#layoutview-childevents

As noted in the docs, you should use `triggerMethod` within your childview, rather than `trigger`!

> childEvents also catches custom events fired by a child view. Take
>   note that the first argument to a childEvents handler is the child
>   view itself. Caution: Events triggered on the child view through
>   this.trigger are not yet supported for LayoutView childEvents. Use
>   strictly triggerMethod within the child view.

Comment: Well that would probably do it. I better get to reading the docs more, apparently! Will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
childEvents: {
  "next:question": this.showNextQuestion,
}
```

Or see if you have better luck with `triggerMethod`

```
events: {
    "click #next":function(e){
        this.triggerMethod("next:question")
   }
}
```

Then in your layout have a method called `onChildviewNextQuestion`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried the first one already. I attempted various permutations of the examples in the Documentation, as well as an anonymous function with a simple `console.log()` to check whether it would fire